# Command with or without parameter

Tags: macros, definition

How to define a command

```
\def\hello{Hello world!}
```

that can be called with no parameter:

```
\hello
```

or with a parameter:

```
\hello{3}
```

but that won't be displayed anyway (3 shouldn't be displayed, it's an internal number I'll maybe use later, but for now, it should not be displayed)

Comment: It is called an optional argument, used with brackets: `\newcommand\hello[1][]{Hello world!\gdef\savearg{#1}}`, Then `\hello` or `\hello[3]` will work, and `\savearg` will preserve the optional argument.

Comment: see the `xparse` package it has some inrecommended options like the `g` type.

Comment: Thanks @StevenB.Segletes. Even `\newcommand\hello[1][]{Hello World}` works!

Comment: Yes it does, and it throws away the optional argument until you later decide to revise the command definition.

Comment: It's preferable to use a conforming syntax and the usual method for denoting optional arguments in LaTeX is with `[]`. So `\newcommand\hello[1][]{Hello world}` is the best choice. With `xparse` there is a finer control for optional arguments.

Comment: @egreg Just to be sure to understand, your command is exactly the same?

Comment: @Basj Yes, it's the same.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Steven B. Segletes in a comment,

```
\newcommand\hello[1][]{Hello world!\gdef\savearg{#1}}
```

works and saves the optional argument. If the optional argument is not required, then

```
\newcommand\hello[1][]{Hello World}
```

is the solution.